# Is there any way to make Gmail automatically delete out-of-office replies from cc addresses?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

It's just quite a nuisance when you send out an email with only one or two `to` addresses and a whole bunch of `cc`/`bcc` addresses just because they were previously part of the email chain and you then get spammed with half a dozen out-of-office replies from people that are in no way relevant to the conversation.

Obviously I care about out-of-office replies from the people in the `to` field, but as far as I'm concerned, I'd rather not receive the ones from people in the `cc` list. Unfortunately I can't do much about them sending them, so I'm hoping to find some way of filtering them instead. If I can't find a way of doing this on Gmail, I might have to try to do this at a mail server level and route all my mail through a server I control.

Is there any way this can be filtered out in Gmail? Is there an alternative I could use where this could be done?

Comment: Gmail filters aren't that complex. Certainly a filter can't act on an incoming message based on information in the message that prompted the reply; only on the information in the incoming message.

Comment: That's pretty much why I'm asking the question; it's certainly not straight forward. On the other hand, pretty much every out-of-office response I've seen *does* contain all the information of the original message and therefore also technically all the required information - though not in a convenient format I'll grant you. I also don't see how I could make a Gmail filter work for this, but I'm hoping there are alternatives.